# How to add a swagger dependency in pubspec.yaml of flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, swagger

I'm a new developers with flutter, and i want to use "swagger" in my application. I add the dependencies of swagger in pubspec.yaml, but there's always an error.

pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  english_words: ^3.1.0
  swagger: ^1.0.0
```

when i clicked Packages get, this is the following output:

```
Running "flutter packages get" in my_first_app...               
Because my_first_app depends on swagger ^1.0.0 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.

pub get failed (1)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can i use swagger in my Flutter application?

Answer (score 2):

You probably should use instead

```
open_api: ^2.0.1
```

`swagger` is deprecated and not compatible with Dart 2 and the requested version `1.0.0` doesn't exist at all.

From https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/swagger#-readme-tab-

[image]

Comment: When i change the version of swagger to : swagger: ^0.0.2 this is the following output :
Running "flutter packages get" in my_first_app...               
The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.9.4.flutter-f9ebf21297.
Because my_first_app depends on swagger >=0.0.2 which requires SDK version >=1.0.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1)
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Why would you do that. The package is deprecated and as I said not compatible with Flutter because it depends on Dart 1.

Comment: So, i can't use swagger with Flutter ?

Comment: Thank you, you mean that openapi dependencies replace swagger dependencies in pubspec.yaml up to now

Comment: how to replace swagger in flutter?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. open_api **is** swagger. Just use `open_api`